# How to merge multiple text file located in two different folders and create a new column in the combine file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, text, merge, multiple-columns, concatenation

All,

I have two folders that contains ~1000 txt files. Say Folder 1 and Folder 2. I would like to combine all the files in one txt file and create a new column call "Label" and assign labels such that if 001.txt file belong to Folder 1, the the label column will have "Folder 1" as a label.Likewise, if the txt file belong to "Folder 2" than the label will "Folder 2". So far I have below code, where I manage to marge all the txt file in folder 1 and rename to folder 1, but that's not What I want.

Folder1=001.txt,002.txt....1000.txt

Folder2=001.txt,002.txt....1000.txt

**Reference dataset can be found** [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/)
**Download File name reference**  = polarity dataset v1.0

```
import fileinput
import glob

file_list = glob.glob("*txt") #Looking at the files that has .txt extension
with open('Folder1.txt', 'w') as file:     
    input_lines = fileinput.input(file_list)
    file.writelines(input_lines)
```

Comment: When you say "create a new column," does it mean that some columns already exist?

Comment: @DYZ.. No there are no columns in the text files. My text file looks like movie review. Please use this link for  reference : http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/ . File Name: polarity dataset v1.0